# When using screen sharing, how can I switch spaces on local machine while remote machine is in full screen?

Tags: spaces, screen-sharing

I want to keep a remote machine open in full screen and be able to switch to and from that space on my local machine. On my local machine I have f1 and f2 set to switch spaces, but all keyboard entries go to the remote machine so I have to exit full screen in order to access my local machine and switch spaces.

f1 and f2 are not set to do anything on the local machine so I just get the "this key doesn't do anything" beep.

Is there maybe a way to have some keys not forward to the remote machine and only register on the local machine? or am I missing something and there is another way to do this?

Both machines are running 12.1.

Edit: I notice now that this happens even when not in full screen. if screen sharing is the app in focus all keyboard input goes to the remote machine. I have to use mouse to unfocus screen sharing in order for keyboard to interact with local machine.

Comment: Is this new to Monterey? Just tested on older OSes & so long as the local & remote commands are not the same as each other I can invoke Space switching on either by pressing the keys appropriate to each Mac - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgetj.gif [local Mac has blue desktop pic & safari, remote has purple]

Comment: i don’t know if this is new. i hope it’s not new and i just have something set wrong some how. although i don’t know what that could be

Comment: I can't repro your issue. I set F1 & F2 to switch Spaces on the remote & left the usual Ctrl/num & Ctrl/arrows to switch on the local. Each worked just fine, whether the remote was in fullscreen or not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved-ish. I changed moving/switching spaces back to the default ctrl/arrows on the local machine and I'm able to switch normally.

Perhaps using function keys introduces some sort of issue. I tried putting back to <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> and the same thing happened as before.

I've been using <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> for quite some time so just going to take some muscle memory retraining I guess.

Comment: Confirmed. I hadn't tested it that way round. F-keys on the local don't register when you're in the remote. Ctrl/num works just fine & f-keys work inside the remote. Go figure;))